# How to display a input textbox of particular div when selecting a value from select box?

Tags: jquery

I have a select box containing some values shown below :

```
<div>
<select class="skilltest">
     <option>Enter</option>
     <option class="add">Add</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="disableskill">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Advanced" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="tell me your Skill level">
</div>


//next same div as above


<div>
<select class="skilltest">
     <option>Enter</option>
     <option class="add">Add</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="disableskill">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Advanced" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="tell me your Skill level">
</div>
```

I have multiple divs using the class padnone. When I am clicking the value advanced of a particular div class padnone, it should display the input text box inside the div class named disableskill of that particular main div.

I have written a jquery for it, but it is displaying all the input text boxes of every div.

```
$("select.skilltest").change(function()
{

    alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    var skillvalue=$(this).val();
    alert(skillvalue);
    if(skillvalue  == "add")
    {
        alert("Checkbox is checked.");
        $(this).find("div.disableskill").show();


    }
    else{

        $(this).find("div.disableskill").hide();

    }
});
```

Can anyone say a solution for this ?

Comment: Can you please explain in simple words what do you want to happen when user choose from the dropdown?

Comment: I have a multiple divs containing the same select box and input text box. intially the input textbox is invisible. when i am slecting the value add from dropdown, it displays the input textbox of that particular div.\

Comment: ok, do you work with css? or js only?

Comment: js...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you well, try this:

```js
$("div.disableskill").hide();

$("select.skilltest").change(function()
{
    var closestSelect = $(this).parent();  
    var skillvalue = $(this).val();
    
    if(skillvalue  == "Add")
    {
      $(closestSelect).next().show();
    }
    else{
           $(closestSelect).next().hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <select class="skilltest">
     <option>Enter</option>
     <option class="add">Add</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="disableskill">
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="Advanced" id="exampleInputName"  placeholder="tell me your Skill level">
</div>



//next same div as above


<div>
<select class="skilltest">
     <option>Enter</option>
     <option class="add">Add</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="disableskill">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Advanced" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="tell me your Skill level">
</div>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: when clicking the select box

Comment: It's not from my code. for sure. 
check your browser, sounds like browser issues, BTY, What browser you use? it doesnt matter but i just curious

Comment: Video of screen recording (tested on firefox and chrome) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1PRYJNz1OgvbHZnRTZ2SzFnSVk